# GitHub Actions cronjob trigger seems to trigger an hour later

Tags: github, cron, github-actions

While I have used GitHub Actions (with push triggers), I'm fairly new to scheduling them based on specified time. Simply: I have a simple `cronjob` running on GitHub Actions with the following trigger:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 0 * * *"
```

This should run at UTC 0h daily, but what I'm seeing in the logs is that it starts at least 1 hour later, between 01:04-01:11 UTC. I understand that GitHub Actions scheduling is such that it can be delayed by minutes and such, but this seem odd that it's delayed by more than an hour in a fairly consistent manner for a week and a half now.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this? I know this is small, but it's kind of nagging and something I wanted to understand should I need events to happen at specified time.

Comment: I don't think you can do much about that – midnight is probably the biggest of all queues for cron triggers. See, for example, [here](https://github.community/t/no-assurance-on-scheduled-jobs/133753) or [here](https://github.community/t/scheduled-action-running-consistently-late/138025).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks. I had came across a couple of github community posts. Most was focused on a job not running or it not running every 5 minutes for example. Thought the one hour difference might have been a timezone daylight savings thing (I'm in Arizona where there's no DS) though I thought that would be quite weird since runners are on UTC anyway. I'm curious if there's a time where there's not much of a backlog so it runs at an expected time.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have a repo with jobs running at 11:00 and 22:00 UTC, and they typically run within two minutes of that time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and see if that works.

Answer (score 6):

When you set up a GitHub Actions workflow with a **schedule**, you're essentially requesting GitHub to schedule that workflow for you. There is no guarantee that the workflow will run exactly at that time.

In a discussion in the GitHub Support Community ([No assurance on scheduled jobs?](https://github.community/t/no-assurance-on-scheduled-jobs/133753)), Github partner [@brightran](https://github.community/u/brightran/summary) said that many times, there may be a delay when triggering the scheduled workflow:

> Generally, the delay time is about 3 to 10 minutes. Sometimes, it may
> be more, even dozens of minutes, or more than one hour.

He also said that if the delay time is too long, the scheduled workflow may be not triggered at that day. Therefore, it's not recommended to use GitHub Actions scheduled workflows for production tasks that require execution guarantee.

[Source](https://upptime.js.org/blog/2021/01/22/github-actions-schedule-not-working/)

Comment: Thanks. I think ultimately my question evolved into when is the best time to run it to minimize the delay as everyone seems to schedule it for UTC 0.